# Problem while writing a small parser in Haskell using Parsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I am trying to write a parser for a small language with the following piece of code

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Token

data Exp = Atom String | Op String Exp

instance Show Exp where
  show (Atom x) = x
  show (Op f x) = f ++ "(" ++ (show x) ++ ")"

parse_exp :: Parser Exp
parse_exp = (try parse_atom) <|> parse_op

parse_atom :: Parser Exp
parse_atom = do
  x <- many1 letter
  return (Atom x)

parse_op :: Parser Exp
parse_op = do
  x <- many1 letter
  char '(' 
  y <- parse_exp
  char ')'
  return (Op x y)
```

But when I type in ghci

```
>>> parse (parse_exp <* eof) "<error>" "s(t)"
```

I get the output

```
Left "<error>" (line 1, column 2):
unexpected '('
expecting letter or end of input
```

If I redefine `parse_exp` as

```
parse_exp = (try parse_op) <|> parse_atom
```

then with I get correct result

```
>>> parse (parse_exp <* eof) "<error>" "s(t)"
Right s(t)
```

But I am confused why the first one does not work. Is there a general fix to these kinds of problems in parsing?

Answer (score 5):

When a Parsec parser, like `parse_atom`, is run on a particular string, there are four possible results:

1. It succeeds, consuming some input.
2. It fails, consuming some input.
3. It succeeds, consuming no input.
4. It fails, consuming no input.

In the Parsec source code, these are referred to as "consumed ok", "consumed err", "empty ok" and "empty err" (sometimes abbreviated cok, cerr, eok, eerr).

When two Parsec parsers are used in an alternative, like `p <|> q`, here's how it's parsed.  First, Parsec tries to parse with `p`.  Then:

- If this results in "consumed ok" or "empty ok", the parse succeeds and this becomes the result of the entire parser `p <|> q`.
- If this results in "empty err", Parsec tries the alternative `q`, and this becomes the result of the entire `p <|> q` parser.
- If this results in "consumed err", the entire parser `p <|> q` fails with "consumed err" (cerr).

Note the critical difference between `p` returning cerr (which causes the whole parser to fail) versus returning eerr (which causes the alternative parser `q` to be tried).

The `try` function changes the behavior of a parser by converting a "cerr" result to an "eerr" result.

This means that if you are trying to parse the text `"s(t)"` with different parsers:

- with the parser `parse_atom <|> parse_op`, the parser `parse_atom` returns "cok" consuming `"s"` and leaving unparseable text `"(t)"` which causes an error
- with the parser `try parse_atom <|> parse_op`, the parser `parse_atom` *still* returns "cok" consuming `"s"`, so the `try` (which only changes cerr to eerr) has no effect, and the unparseable text `"(t)"` causes the same error
- with the parser `parse_op <|> parse_atom`, the parser `parse_op` successfully parses the string (actually, it doesn't because the recursive call to `parse_exp` can't parse `"t"`, but let's ignore that); however, if the same parser was used on the text `"s"`, then `parse_op` would consume the `"s"` before failing (i.e., cerr), causing the entire parse to fail instead of trying the alternative `parse_atom`
- with the parser `try parse_op <|> parse_atom`, this would parse `"s(t)"`, exactly as the previous example, and the `try` would have no effect; however, it would *also* work on the text `"s"`, because `parse_op` would consume the `"s"` before failing with cerr, then `try` would "rescue" the parse by turning the cerr into an eerr, and the alternative `parse_atom` would be checked, successfully parsing (cok) the atom `"s"`.

That's why the "correct" parser for your problem is `try parse_op <|> parse_atom`.

Be warned that this behavior isn't a fundamental aspect of monadic parsers.  It's a design choice made by Parsec (and compatible parsers like Megaparsec).  Other monadic parsers can have different rules for how alternatives with `<|>` work.

The "general fix" for these kind of Parsec parsing problems is to be aware of the facts that in the expression `p <|> q`:

- `p` is tried first, and if it succeeds, `q` will be ignored, even if `q` would provide a "longer" or "better" or "more sensible" parse or avoid additional parsing errors further down the road.  In `parse_atom <|> parse_op`, because `parse_atom` can succeed on strings meant for `parse_op`, this order won't work correctly.
- `q` is only tried if `p` fails **without consuming input**.  You must arrange for `p` to not consume anything on failure, possibly by using `try`, if you expect the alternative `q` to be checked.  So, `parse_op <|> parse_atom` isn't going to work if `parse_op` starts to consume something (like an identifier) before realizing it can't continue and returning cerr.

As an alternative to using `try`, you can also think more carefully about the structure of your parser.  An alternative way of writing `parse_exp`, for example, would be:

```
parse_exp :: Parser Exp
parse_exp = do
  -- there's always an identifier
  x <- many1 letter
  -- there *might* be an expression in parentheses
  y <- optionMaybe (parens parse_exp)
  case y of
    Nothing -> return (Atom x)
    Just y' -> return (Op x y')

  where parens = between (char '(') (char ')')
```

This can be written a little more concisely, but even then it's not as "elegant" as something like `try parse_op <|> parse_atom`.  (It performs better, though, so that might be a consideration in some applications.)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the string `"s"` counts as an atom according to your definitions. Try this:

```
parse parse_atom "" "s(t)"
> Atom "s"
```

So your parser `parse_exp` actually succeeds, returning `Atom "s"`, but then you also expect an EOF right after it, and that's where it fails, encountering an open paren instead of an EOF (just like the error message says!)

When you swap the alternative around, it would first attempt `parse_op`, which would succeed, returning `Op "s" "t"`, and then encounter EOF, just as expected.

Comment: Is there way where I can parse the whole string correctly? If I delete the eof then the parser stops at s, but I want to parse the whole string "s(t)"

Comment: That's what the flipped atlternative will do