# Parsec `try` should backtrack

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

Isn't `Parsec`'s `try` supposed to backtrack when it encounters failure?

For instance, if I have the code

```hs
import Control.Applicative ((<|>))
import Debug.Trace
import Text.Parsec (try)
import Text.Parsec.Combinator (eof)
import Text.Parsec.String (Parser)
import qualified Data.Char as Char
import qualified Text.Parsec as Parsec

data Func = Add | Sub deriving (Show)

add :: Parser Func
add = do
    Parsec.string "+"
    Parsec.notFollowedBy $ Parsec.satisfy (\_-> True)
    return Add

sub :: Parser Func
sub = do
    Parsec.string "-"
    Parsec.notFollowedBy $ Parsec.satisfy (\_-> True)
    return Sub

func :: Parser Func
func = add <|> sub

data AST = 
      Primitive String
    | BinOp Func AST AST
  deriving (Show)

primitive :: Parser AST
primitive = do
    str <- Parsec.many1 $ Parsec.satisfy $ not . Char.isSpace
    trace "primitive returning" $ return $ Primitive str

binOp :: Parser AST
binOp = do
    lhs <- parser
    Parsec.spaces
    operation <- func
    Parsec.spaces
    rhs <- parser
    return $ BinOp operation lhs rhs

parser :: Parser AST
parser = try primitive <|> binOp

sample :: String
sample = "+#-! + -$!&+"

main :: IO ()
main = print $ Parsec.parse (parser <* eof) "failure" sample
```

I get the output:

```
primitive returning
Left "failure" (line 1, column 5):
unexpected ' '
expecting end of input
```

However, from my understanding, when the parser encounters `try primitive <|> binOp` and `primitive` fails, it should go to the `binOp` option.

Desired parse is

```
BinOp Add (Primitive "+#-!") (Primitive "-$!&+")
```

Comment: Why should `try primitive` backtrack? The `primitive` parse succeeded! It's the `(<* eof)` that failed.

Comment: It's possible that this is closely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62596485/7203016), and you may find my answer there helpful.

Comment: I think (haven't tested) that the problem is in `add` and `sub`. `Parsec.notFollowedBy` is meant to succeed when the inner parser fails but `Parsec.satisfy (\_-> True)` always succeed if there is any output left. Therefore `Parsec.notFollowedBy $ Parsec.satisfy (\_-> True)` should always fail unless no more characters are remaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `try` doesn't actually use the word "backtrack".  What it says is:

> The parser `try p` behaves like parser `p`, except that it pretends that it hasn't consumed any input when an error occurs.

This may make little sense until you match it up with the documentation for the `(<|>)` operator which states:

> The parser `p <|> q` first applies `p`. If it succeeds, the value of `p` is returned. If `p` fails *without consuming any input,* parser `q` is tried.

Note the emphasized phrase -- that's emphasis in the original documentation, not emphasis I've added.

Here's how this leads to "backtracking".  Consider a simplified version of your parser that allows no spaces, only single-letter primitives, and addition of two primitives as the only operation:

```
...
import Text.Parsec as Parsec
import Text.Parser.Char as Parsec
...

add :: Parser Func
add = do
  Parsec.string "+"
  return Add

primitive :: Parser AST
primitive = do
  c <- Parsec.letter
  return $ Primitive (c:"")

binOp :: Parser AST
binOp = do
  lhs <- primitive
  operation <- add
  rhs <- primitive
  return $ BinOp operation lhs rhs

parser :: Parser AST
parser = binOp <|> primitive
```

This parser doesn't work.  It parses `"x+y"` okay:

```
λ> parseTest parser "x+y"
BinOp Add (Primitive "x") (Primitive "y")
```

but it fails to parse `"x"` alone:

```
λ> parseTest parser "x"
parse error at (line 1, column 2):
unexpected end of input
expecting "+"
```

The problem in this second case is that the `<|>` operator tries `binOp` first.  The `binOp` parser consumes a primitive, namely `"x"`, and then fails to parse `add` (because there's no `"+"` character).  As a result, `binOp` fails *after consuming input*.  The `<|>` doesn't try its right-hand side alternative parser (`primitive`) because `p <|> q` only tries `q` if `p` fails without consuming input, and that's not what happened here.  In other words, by default, after the left-hand side of the alternative consumes some input and then fails, there is no "backtracking" to put that consumed input back.

The `try` combinator changes this behavior by "undoing" the consumption of input in case of failure.  If we fix the parser:

```
parser :: Parser AST
parser = try binOp <|> primitive
```

then it works fine on the input `"x"`:

```
λ> parseTest parser "x"
Primitive "x"
```

As before, the `<|>` operator tries the `try binOp` parser first.  The `try binOp` parser acts just like `binOp` -- it consumes a primitive and then fails to parse `add`, resulting in a "failure after consuming input".  But `try` "backtracks" by replacing this with a "failure without consuming any input" (essentially, putting the input back).  This satisfies the requirement for `<|>` to try the alternative parser `primitive` which, of course, successfully parses `"x"`, and that's the final result of the parse.

How is this different from your situation?  Well, you've got the equivalent of:

```
parser :: Parser AST
parser = try primitive <|> binOp
```

This parser is broken, too.  It works on `"x"`:

```
λ> parseTest parser "x"
Primitive "x"
```

and it "works" on `"x+y"` but returns the wrong answer:

```
λ> parseTest parser "x+y"
Primitive "x"
```

The problem is that the `<|>` first tries the `try primitive` parser, which acts just like `primitive`.  Even in the second test case, it *succeeds* after consuming the primitive `"x"` (leaving `"+y"` yet to be parsed).  Note that `try` has no effect, because the only thing `try` does is take "failure after consuming input" and replace it with "failure without consuming any input", but `primitive` doesn't fail!  It succeeds!  So, there's no backtracking because there's no failure to backtrack from.  The result of `parser` is `Primitive "x"`, and now there's some unparseable garbage `"+y"` left that will trigger a failure in some other parser that follows `parser`, like `eof`.

So, to start to fix your parser, you could replace the definition of `parser` with:

```
parser :: Parser AST
parser = try binOp <|> primitive
```

Here, the `try binOp` will start to parse a `binOp`, and if it fails part way through (e.g., after parsing a primitive but not finding an operator), then `try` will trigger backtracking so the `primitive` parser can be tried instead.

Unfortunately, this will cause an infinite loop in your parser because `parser` starts by trying `binOp` which starts by invoking `parser` (for the left-hand side) which starts by trying `binOp`, etc., etc., and neither parser makes any progress.

There are a few solutions to this problem.  There is machinery in `Text.Parsec.Expr` for handling expressions in general, and there are functions like `sepBy` or `chainl1` for correctly parsing a sequence of terms separated by operators (without creating an infinite loop).

If you want to do it manually, you'll end up having to do something like:

```
parser :: Parser AST
parser = do
  -- there's always a primitive
  lhs <- primitive
  Parsec.spaces
  -- it may be followed by some binOp/primitives
  followedByBinOp lhs

followedByBinOp :: AST -> Parser AST
followedByBinOp lhs =
  -- if there's another binop/primitive
  (do operator <- func
      Parsec.spaces
      rhs <- primitive
      Parsec.spaces
      -- then loop with a new LHS
      followedByBinOp (BinOp operator lhs rhs)
  -- otherwise, return what we've got
  <|> return lhs)
```

This is super ugly, which is why `chainl1` was invented.  The above can be replaced with:

```
parser :: Parser AST
parser = Parsec.chainl1 (primitive <* Parsec.spaces) (BinOp <$> func <* Parsec.spaces)
```

With either of these versions of `parser`, your parser *still* won't work because of two more problems.  First, your `primitive` doesn't know when to stop:

```
primitive :: Parser AST
primitive = do
    str <- Parsec.many1 $ Parsec.satisfy $ not . Char.isSpace
    trace "primitive returning" $ return $ Primitive str
```

Here, the only way to end a primitive is with a space.  That means that the expression `"x+y+z"` is a valid single primitive.  If you try to parse this with `parser`, the initial `lhs <- primitive` will eat the whole string, and you'll get back `Primitive "x+y+z"`.  If you don't mind spaces being mandatory, then you'll be able to get it to parse `"x + y + z"`, but if you'd like spaces to be optional, you'll need to somehow restrict the allowed primitives.  (There's a reason most languages doesn't allow completely arbitrary identifiers.  If `x+y` or -- worse -- `+#-!` -- is a valid identifier, it's hard to parse expressions with infix operators.)

If you allow only alphanumeric strings as primitives, that'll get you a little closer:

```
primitive :: Parser AST
primitive = do
    str <- Parsec.many1 $ Parsec.satisfy $ Char.isAlphaNum
    return $ Primitive str
```

However, your parser *still* won't work because `add` and `sub` are misusing `notFollowedBy`.  Consider `add`:

```
add :: Parser Func
add = do
    Parsec.string "+"
    Parsec.notFollowedBy $ Parsec.satisfy (\_-> True)
    return Add
```

This works by first parsing a `"+"` character.  Then, it tries to parse another character.  If that character satisfies the predicate (which it does because it's always `True`), then the whole parse will fail after consuming input.  That's because `notFollowedBy` is designed to fail if its parser succeeds.  So, except in the case where a `"+"` occurs at the end of the string, this `add` parser always fails after consuming input, aborting the entire parse.

For now, at least, it's probably best to just delete those `notFollowedBy` lines.

Anyway, here's a modified version of your parser that more or less works, but only accepts alphanumeric primitives.  It actually doesn't need to backtrack, so it doesn't use `try` anywhere:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<|>))
import Text.Parsec.Combinator (eof)
import Text.Parsec.String (Parser)
import qualified Data.Char as Char
import qualified Text.Parsec as Parsec

data Func = Add | Sub deriving (Show)

add :: Parser Func
add = do
    Parsec.string "+"
    -- Parsec.notFollowedBy $ Parsec.satisfy (\_-> True)
    return Add

sub :: Parser Func
sub = do
    Parsec.string "-"
    -- Parsec.notFollowedBy $ Parsec.satisfy (\_-> True)
    return Sub

func :: Parser Func
func = add <|> sub

data AST =
      Primitive String
    | BinOp Func AST AST
  deriving (Show)

primitive :: Parser AST
primitive = do
    str <- Parsec.many1 $ Parsec.satisfy $ Char.isAlphaNum
    return $ Primitive str

parser :: Parser AST
parser = do
  -- there's always a primitive
  lhs <- primitive
  Parsec.spaces
  -- it may be followed by some binOp/primitives
  followedByBinOp lhs

followedByBinOp :: AST -> Parser AST
followedByBinOp lhs =
  -- if there's another binop/primitive
  (do operator <- func
      Parsec.spaces
      rhs <- primitive
      Parsec.spaces
      -- then loop with a new LHS
      followedByBinOp (BinOp operator lhs rhs)
  -- otherwise, return what we've got
  <|> return lhs)

sample :: String
sample = "xyz + 15 - 123abc"

main :: IO ()
main = print $ Parsec.parse (parser <* eof) "failure" sample
```