# Why does Parsec stop parsing with multiple parser?

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I'm trying to write a simple parser in Haskell using Parsec but my input "Hello World" is never correctly parsed.

My code looks like this:

```hs
parser = p1 <|> p2

p1 = string "Hello"
p2 = string "Hello World"
```

If I run it I get the error `unexpected whitespace`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`p1` already consumes the tokens "Hello" and therefore `p2` instantly fails because the next token is whitespace.

You could use something like [`try`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.17.0/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:try) to reset the consumed tokens.

```hs
parser = try p1 <|> p2

p1 = string "Hello"
p2 = string "Hello World"
```

Comment: Is it really correct that it consumes "Hello", then `p1` fails so it tries the `p2` branch but starting from that point in the input? That implies that it would succeed on input "HelloHello World", which seems incredibly strange. I thought it was more that the choice operator <|>` commits to the first branch that consumes any tokens, so it never even tries `p2`.

Comment: The suggestion to use `try` is correct, but the diagnosis of the problem is wrong.  Because of how Parsec alternatives work, when `p1` fails **after consuming input**, the alternative fails immediately without ever trying `p2`.  Here's one explanation in [this old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62599761/7203016).